# UIButton Tag Conversion from alphanumeric value

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am getting user-id as String from MongoDB. And I want to set this user-id as tag property for a UIButton. As this user-id is alphanumeric, I can't set this user-id as tag for that UIButton, because tag is of datatype Int. So how can I assign tag as user-id retrieved from MongoDB to that UIButton?

Comment: What exactly does the value coming from mongodb look like?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be doing it this way. Create a dictionary `[String: Int]` to hold the mapping from mongo IDs to tags, then you can use a counter for your tags to get uniqueness there.

If you want you can try using the string's `hashValue` but I don't recommend that.

Another option is using associated values to store the actual string on the button.

At a higher level I'd question why you would want to do any of this. It seems like your program is probably not very well structured. You can ask further questions here or app design questions on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

```
button.tag = Int(yourstring)
```

Make sure your string should not contain characters.

Learn more about it
[Swift Basic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: If the string contains letters, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. At first you were saying that you can't set string as button tag in swift. Then you're saying that you can't set integer as button tag. From the question I am understanding that you want to set user-id retrieved from mongodb as your button tag. But as this retrieved user-id is alphanumeric, you can't set button tag, because swift allows only integer as button tag.

So I suggest either change the datatype of user-id in mongodb to integer or add a new integer field in mongodb for button tag. Or you can use some other values for button tag. To be clear, iOS only allows Int as tag property for any UIElements.

**Edit:**
If you wanted to get Int from your alphanumeric user-id, you can use the following code.

```
 let str = "571db47a342c2e307cb4af35)"
 let components = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
 let part = components.joinWithSeparator("")
 let myint = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(part)!
 //let myint = Int(part) // returns nil because sizeof(Int) = 4 
 //let myint = Double(part) // returns 571473422307435.0
 print(myint)
```

Comment: Is there any solution to Convert my mongodb userid (is in the form of 571db47a342c2e307cb4af35) to Integer.because amusing that user id as my button tag.

Comment: Actually my userid as string is 571db47a342c2e307cb4af35 contains letters and numbers.There is a need to convert that string to Integer.Am waiting to see ur ideas....

Comment: Above code converts alphanumeric to NSNumber only.That Code juz remove the letter in string and my response like this 571473422307435 (571db47a342c2e307cb4af35).I need to convert that alphanumeric to Integer value.Anyways thanks for ur quick response

Comment: You cant convert an Alphanumeric to Integer. But you can extract decimals from your alphanumeric, as I tried. Also that NSNumber could to converted to Int.

Comment: One more point. You cannot convert your user-id to Int because of the size limits. Check my edited answer. That's why I used NSNumber.

Comment: @Rookie Did you find the solution?

Comment: Thanks for ur concern but still didnt get solution.Alternatively I have planned to add unique userid column in mongodb